# Atom text editor - How do I change the default git branch name?

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

When I create a new git repository using the Atom GUI, the default branch name is `master`. I'd like to change this to `main`.

I think the problem is related to Atom, not my git configuration, as when I use `git init` from a terminal the default is `main`. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: I can reproduce the same problem on Ubuntu, so this seems to be a bug. You can [open an issue against the extension](https://github.com/atom/github/issues). I seem to remember a previous question or issue about the same thing, but I can't find it now. I have noticed it myself in the past, but it's never been a big problem for me.

Comment: FWIW, I tried enabling "Git Diagnostics" in the extension settings and initializing a new repo, but it just seems to be doing a normal init, that is, it's not specifying `-b` or anything.

Comment: @wjandrea: cheers for your help. I've raised a bug report [here](https://github.com/atom/github/issues/2755#issue-1197171663)